# npm start is sending a weird "file not found" on fresh install of react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, error-handling, package.json

```
npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\15029\mushrooms/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\15029\mushrooms\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.      
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\15029\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-13T23_57_54_280Z-debug-0.log
```

I've deleted and re-installed node. I tried NPM update, NPM install. I've verified the `package.json` file 100% exists. I don't know what else to do. This is a fresh `create-react-app` installation.

I have been having a boatload of problems with NPM lately. All I did was `create-react-app` and then install Tailwindcss from the tailwind docs. I have the `package.json` file how is it telling me it doesn't exist? I also installed `react-scripts`.

Comment: Where do you run the `npm start`, in the root folder?

Comment: Could you provide the file structures?